# php header not redirect to its url

Tags: php, redirect, header

i need to redirect url

https://vivekp.co/server/apiurl/qwertyuiopl

but its redirect to

https://vivekp.co/server/apiurl/".$youtube_id

how solve this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['urlid'])) {
$url = $_GET["urlid"];
//$url="https://youtube.com/watch?v=fbjfnjnfkjs";

preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);

$youtube_id = $match[1];

$nr="https://vivekp.co/server/apiurl/".$youtube_id;

header('location:$nr');

}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your header like,

```
header('location:'.$nr);
```

Comment: Glad to help @Vicky. Please do upvote..!!

Answer (score 0):

You should either take out the variable from `''` or change it to `""`

```
header("location:$nr");
```

or

```
header('location:'.$nr);
```